# Mongodb on Debian Wheezy apt-key timeout

Tags: mongodb, debian

I´m trying to install mondodb on my vps (Debian Wheezy). I executed:

```
 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10                                                                                                                                                                                               2 ↵
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.1kX6dv1wdB --trustdb-name /etc/apt//trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-squeeze-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-squeeze-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
gpg: agotado el tiempo de espera para el servidor de clavesbuntu.com
gpg: recepción del servidor de claves fallida: error del servidor de claves
```

It keeps telling me that there is no connection with the server and timeout error. 
Is there any other walk-around?
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open port 11371 on your firewall or install it from source

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
```

Note the "hkp://" and the ":80" added to the server parameter.